# Twisted trial hangs between tests

Tags: python, twisted, trial

I'm pretty new to twisted and I'm attempting to write some unit tests using the trial test framework. My tests run and pass as expected, but for some reason trial is hanging between tests. I have to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  after each test to get it to move on to the next one. I'm guessing I have something configured incorrectly or I'm not calling some method I should be to tell trial the test is done.

Here is the class under test:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
import threading
import time


class SomeClass:
   def doSomething(self):
      return self.asyncMethod()

   def asyncMethod(self):
       d = defer.Deferred()
       t = SomeThread(d)
       t.start()
       return d


class SomeThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, d):
        super(SomeThread, self).__init__()
        self.d = d

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(2) # pretend to do something
        retVal = 123
        self.d.callback(retVal)
```

Here is the unit test class:

```
from twisted.trial import unittest
import tested


class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testOne(self):
        sc = tested.SomeClass()
        d = sc.doSomething()
        return d.addCallback(self.allDone)

    def allDone(self, retVal):
        self.assertEquals(retVal, 123)

    def testTwo(self):
        sc = tested.SomeClass()
        d = sc.doSomething()
        return d.addCallback(self.allDone2)

    def allDone2(self, retVal):
        self.assertEquals(retVal, 123)
```

This is what the command line output looks like:

```
me$ trial test.py 
test
  SomeTest
    testOne ... ^C                                                           [OK]
    testTwo ... ^C                                                           [OK]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 8.499s

PASSED (successes=2)
```

Comment: why are you using `threading`?  You probably should be using [`deferToThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread.html)

Comment: The problem appears to have something to do with the sleep in conjunction with the threading. If I leave the threading in and take the sleep out it works. I also got it to work by taking out the threading altogether and using reactor.callLater() instead. Can anyone explain why the threads cause this issue? I just wanted to simulate a long operation like a database query.

Comment: I tried using deferToThread() and that also works quite well. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *guess* your problem has to do with your threads. Twisted is not thread-safe, and if you need to interface with threads you should let the reactor handle things by using `deferToThread`, `callInThread`, `callFromThread`.
See [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html) for info on how to be thread-safe with Twisted.